# Potential and Kinetic Energy of a Travelling Wave

Tags: energy, waves

In a book(that I was going through), it is given that the kinetic and potential energy of a travelling wave is always the same but the proof for this statement is not given.
Kindly express your respective insights regarding the same.

Comment: [Energy and Power of a Wave](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Book%3A_University_Physics_I_-_Mechanics_Sound_Oscillations_and_Waves_(OpenStax)/16%3A_Waves/16.05%3A_Energy_and_Power_of_a_Wave)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/255727/energy-in-a-sound-wave-possible-error?rq=1

Comment: @GiorgioP thanks